# SVN patch partial application

Tags: svn

Is it possible to apply an svn patch (generated by 'svn diff > file.patch') partially? Ideally on a directory by directory basis, for example I have my patch

```
dirA/stuff/file
dirB/stuff/file
dirB/stuff/file2
dirC/stuff/file
```

I'd like to apply all the changes in dirA, then dirB and so on